# How do I turn off the Resource Pack music in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, minecraft-resource-packs

I recently downloaded the Party Island Pack on Minecraft: Xbox One Edition, but I really despise the music that plays when I’m in game with the Pack. I tried turning my music down, but it doesn’t work. Does anyone know any commands or just anything that would turn it off?

Comment: Just remove the music from the pack if you don't like it.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that on Xbox One edition @FabianRöling

Comment: Someone must have created the pack.

Comment: Are you really playing [Minecraft: Xbox One Edition](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Xbox_One_Edition), a game that was discontinued in 2017?